# Parametrisation of recursive method without global variable

Tags: java, recursion, global-variables

As an example we're combing through the permutations of the integer `123456789`. Inspired by [Heap's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap%27s_algorithm), we have the following

```
public static ArrayList<String> comb(char[] seq, int n, ArrayList<String> box){
        if(n == 1){
            if (isSquare(Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(seq)))) {
                box.add(String.valueOf(seq));
            }
        } else {
            for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
                comb(seq,n-1, box);
                int j;
                if ((n%2)==0) {
                    j = i;
                } else {
                    j = 0;
                }
                char temp = seq[n-1];              
                seq[n-1] = seq[j];
                seq[j] = temp;                
            }
        }
        return box;
    }
```

In the present case we're interested whether a particular permutation is a square of an integer. Realised by

```
public static boolean isSquare(int n) {
    if ((n%10)==2 || (n%10) ==3 || (n%10)==7 || (n%10) == 8) {
        return false;
    } else if ( (Math.sqrt(n)) % 1 ==0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

However, to be able to use `comb` I must initialise an empty array outside of the method. What should I do to avoid inducing the need for global variable?  I would still like to obtain a `box` with all solutions. I realise my error is in the parametrisation of `comb` .

Comment: "I must initialise an empty array outside of the method. What should I do to avoid inducing the need for global variable?" Pass it as a parameter.

Comment: The problem is not really the need for a creation of an array outside of the method, you can circument that. But the problem is that you alter the ArrayList **and** the `seq` array, mutating (the contents of) your parameters is generally frowned upon because a caller might / will not expect that.

Answer (score 0):

Create a function that "wraps" the original recursive function, provides it with every parameter it needs and creates copies of objects if necessary:

Let's say you renamed your `comb(...)` function to `combRecursive(...)` for the sake of convenient naming.

```
public static ArrayList<String> comb(char[] seq, int n){
    char[] seqCopy = Arrays.copyOf(seq, seq.length);
    return combRecursive(seqCopy, n, new ArrayList());
}
```